# pop() in stack is not deleting any elements

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a basic *while* cycle to delete the elements of a stack one by one, it wasn't working so i put some flags and it turns out that whenever i did  `Temp.pop()`, it wasn't doing anything, the elements remained intact

Here's the while cycle

```
void sort(stack<Tar> Temp){

    int sizi=Temp.size(), sizf=0;

    while (sizi>sizf){
        cout<<"before"<<Temp.size()<<endl;
        Temp.pop();
        cout<<"after"<<Temp.size()<<endl;
        sizf++;
    }
}
```

Here's my stack template

```
    template <class T>
class stack {
    node<T> *pFirst;
    int n;
    public:
        typedef node<T> *pos;
        stack();    
        ~stack();    
        bool isEmpty();    
        void push(T x);
        void pop();
        T top();
        pos first();    
        void next(pos &pValue);     
        T* get(pos pValue);     //copy
        void insert(T &x, pos pValue);     //copy
        void insert(const T &x, pos pValue);     //copy
        void erase(pos pValue);     //copy
        int size();    //copy

};

template <class T>
stack<T>::stack(){
    n = 0; 
    pFirst = NULL;
}

template <class T>
stack<T>::~stack(){
    node<T> *pTemp;
    while(pFirst != NULL){
        pTemp = pFirst;
        pFirst = pFirst->next;
        delete pTemp;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool stack<T>::isEmpty(){
    return pFirst == NULL;
}

template <class T>
typename stack<T>::pos stack<T>::first(){
    return pFirst;
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::next(pos &pValue){
    if (pValue != NULL)
        pValue = pValue->next;
}

template <class T>
T* stack<T>::get(pos pValue){
    if (pValue != NULL)
        return &(pValue->info);
    return NULL;
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::insert(T &x, pos pValue){
    node<T> *pNew = new node<T>();
    pNew->info = x;
    pNew->next = pValue;
    if (pFirst == NULL || pValue == pFirst)
        pFirst = pNew;
    else{
        node<T> *pTemp = pFirst;
        while(pTemp->next != pValue)
            pTemp = pTemp->next;
        pTemp->next = pNew;
    }
    n++;
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(T x){
    stack<T>::insert(x, first());
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::pop(){
    delete (first());
}

template <class T>
T stack<T>::top(){
    return *get(first());
}

template <class T>
int stack<T>::size(){
    return n;
}
```

I am aware that some of those functions aren't being used but I don't think they have anything to do with this issue

And the node

```
#ifndef _node_h_
#define _node_h_

template <class T>
class node {
    public:
        T info;
        node<T> *next;
};

#endif
```

The output is:

***before16***

***after16***

The size of Temp is 16 so, as you can see, it's not deleting anything.
Not only that but windows says the program stops working.

I think it has to do with memory allocation but I'm not sure

Comment: Based on the degree of your knowledge (looking at your comments) and the complexity (not necessarily a good thing) of the code, could it be you have not written it yourself? Is this homework? edit: Also: If this *is* your code, you may want to publish it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , because there are several things not really good (e.g.: in the destructor, you may want to prefer to call a pop() that never throws, instead of duplicating the code for deletion)

Comment: Note that [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) already exists.

Comment: @SebastianMach Since the code is not working as intended it is off topic for Code Review.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well clearly the problem is that your pop function doesn't change the size of the stack.

I would expect pop to be implemented something like this

```
template <class T>
void stack<T>::pop() {
    node<T>* pTemp = pFirst;
    pFirst = pFirst->next; // remove first node from stack
    --n;                   // decrease size of stack by one
    delete pTemp;          // delete node removed
}
```

Plus some additional error checking for calling pop on an empty stack.

Comment: Doesn't that happen "automatically" when I delete the first position?

Comment: @Ana No, what gives you that idea? All `delete` does is calls the destructor for `Node` and frees the memory. It's up to you to manipulate `n` and `pFirst` so that the node is actually removed from your stack.

Comment: You can see in the [documentation for delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) that it destroys a single object. It doesn't know anything about the rest of your container.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `delete (first())` only deletes the first node, but it doesn't actually unlink the node and don't change the size.

In fact, since you're calling `pop` in a loop you will `delete` the same pointer over and over again, and have *undefined behavior*.